# How to place "however" and "therefore" in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Adverb "however" is often used to mean the opposition of the current sentence to the previous one(s). I have seen it being placed differently within a sentence by different people whose English levels are unknown to me. For example:

- He said that A and B were bad. However, A and B are good.
- He said that A and B were bad. A and B are, however, good.
- He said that A and B were bad. A and B, however, are good.
- He said that A and B were bad. A, however, and B are good.

My vague grammatical knowledge is that when an adverb modifies the verb of a sentence, it is most often placed after the verb or between the verbs if the first verb is "is", "can", etc.
Does "however" modify the entire sentence, or the verb of the sentence?

Similarly, I wonder the same thing about how to place adverb "therefore" in a sentence.

Thanks.

Comment: The first three of your examples are all valid options, but the fourth wouldn't get past an editor.

Comment: What ralph.m said, and you can put "however" at the end of the sentence.